# Remapping Ctrl-(h j k l) to move between windows

Tags: vimrc, gvim

Im trying to increase my efficiency at moving between buffers, and the Ctrl-w-(hjkl) movement doesn't work for me. How can I remap Ctrl-(hjkl) to the Ctrl-w version? I have already tried:

```
inoremap <C-j> <C-wj>
```

but that doesnt work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You almost had it. Try:

```
noremap <C-h> <C-w>h
noremap <C-j> <C-w>j
noremap <C-k> <C-w>k
noremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

You can also add the `inoremap` if you want it to work from insert mode.

Comment: It worked, although I had to move it to the top of my .vimrc. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: I accidentally made an edit to this answer, please reject it! Sorry!